# Which is the earliest scripture to use the word "varna" to denote caste?

Tags: scripture, caste-system, sanskrit, terminology, etymology

The Rig Vedic Purusha Sukta mentions Rajanya, Brahmin, Vaishya and Sudra, but doesn't call them Varnas.  Which scripture first uses the word *varna* for the classification-scheme?

Answer (score 1):

For the first genuine use of *varna* to mean *caste*, we must go to the Bhagavad Gita, considered to have been written around/before the start of the Common Era, perhaps around 400 BCE:

> [**Bhagavad Gita 4.13**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shrimad-bhagavad-gita/d/doc419869.html)
>
> ---
>
> **चातुर्-वर्ण्यं** मया सृष्टं गुण-कर्म-विभागशः ।
> तस्य कर्तारम् अपि मां विद्ध्य् अकर्तारम् अव्ययम् ॥ १३ ॥
>
> **cātur-varṇyaṃ** mayā sṛṣṭaṃ guṇa-karma-vibhāgaśaḥ |
> tasya kartāram api māṃ viddhy akartāram avyayam ||
>
> [**cātur-varṇyam** refers to the system of the four social orders]
>
> The fourfold system of varṇas (brāhmaṇa, kṣatriya, vaiśya and śūdra) was created by Me according to divisions of quality (guṇa) and work (karma). Although I am the creator of this system, you should know that I am the immutable non-doer.

---

*Varna* implying *caste* appears only once in the Rig Veda, and this takes a bit of a liberal interpretation. Sāyaṇa, in his commentary on the text, took this interpretation. It can't really be considered the *first* example, since it merely shows the word's early use; it merely *implies* the idea of caste, not necessarily *meaning* it completely.

> **[Rig Veda 3.34.9](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc831910.html)**
>
> ---
>
> ससानात्याँ उत सूर्यं ससानेन्द्रः ससान पुरुभोजसं गाम् ।
> हिरण्ययमुत भोगं ससान हत्वी **दस्यून्प्रार्यं वर्णमावत्** ॥
>
> | sasānātyām̐ uta sūryaṃ sasānendraḥ sasāna purubhojasaṃ gām |
> | --- |
>
> English:
> “He gave horses, he gave also the sun, and Indra gave also the many-nourishing cow; he gave golden treasure, and having destroyed the **dasyus, he protected the ārya tribe**.”
>
> ---
>
> Commentary by Sāyaṇa: Ṛgveda-bhāṣya:
> The ārya tribe: **ārya varṇam** = implies only the best tribe, or order, uttamam varṇam, or the three first **castes** collectively